# How to use operator "^" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, operator-keyword

I'm trying to use `^` operator in javascript, like:

```
0.66666666666666666666666666666667^1.5
```

should equal

```
0,54433105395181735515495201660131
```

But when I'm trying to do it, it won't return me anything, it will return either 67,0 or 1, depending on my attempts.

#### Desired Output

```
console.log(100 * 0.66666666666666666666666666666667^1.5);
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You need to take the [exponenciation operator `**`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Exponentiation_(**))instead of [bitwise XOR `^`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_XOR).

Alternate use the classing [`Math.pow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow).

```js
console.log(0.66666666666666666666666666666667 ** 1.5)
```

Answer (score 2):

`^` means XOR in JavaScript. If you want exponentiation, you have to use `Math.pow` or `**` instead.